# Copy unique records from one workbook to another master workbook

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I need some help with copying unique records from one workbook to a master workbook please.

Each month I receive a new workbook with data and I want to be able to copy all new records in that new workbook to one master workbook which will have all the amalgamted records. There is one unique reference field which can be used for the lookup to identify a new record.
In addition to this what I want to do is update values which are in 3 columns for ALL existing records on the master workbook which might be on the new workbook.

Example

Master workbook

```
Ref Name Value 1 Value 2 Value 3 Description
123 TR   100     50      200     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
111 WE   90      45      400     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

New workbook

```
Ref Name Value 1 Value 2 Value 3 Description
123 TR   300     200      200     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
456 MA   100     500      700     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Update master workbook

```
Ref Name Value 1 Value 2 Value 3 Description
123 TR    300     200     200    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
111 WE    90      45      400    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
456 MA    100     500     700    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I'd appreciate any help with this please. Thanks

Comment: It is quite possible, did you manage to put together any code so far?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small module that does what you want (and even more). I tried to make it as generic as possible, but I had to assert a few things and limit it somehow - otherwise it would get quickly out of hand (as I think it already did.. kind of).

The limitations/assertions are the following:
 1. the records are considered to be laid out only in rows (as per your example).
 2. there is no column checking during the update or insertion of values. The program assumes that both master and new workbooks contain the same columns and laid in the exact same order.
 3. There is no validation check for duplicate reference values. The "ref" column that you indicate as your *primary* key in each data range, is assumed to contain unique values (for that data range).

Apart from those assumptions, my solution is enhanced with flexible arguments (optional or autoconfigurable - see how dataRange is determined) to allow for several types of operation.

- optional *colorAlertOption* flag: allows updated or inserted entries to be colored in order to be more distinguisable (**true** by default)
- optional *rangeWithHeaders* flag: helps to determine if the supplied dataRange argument needs to be resized (remove headers) or not (**true** by default)
- optional *refColIndex* integer: the relative to the dataRange - not the whole worksheet - column number pinpointing the column containing the unique references. (**1** by default)
- required *dataRangeNew*, *dataRangeMaster* (Range) arguments: flexible representations of the data-ranges for the new and master datasets respectively. You can either provide them explicitly (e.g. "$A$1:$D$10") or by giving only a single cell contained anywhere within the data-range. The only predicates are that the data-range should be isolated from other possible data coexisting on the same sheet (by means of blank rows or columns) and that it contains at least 1 row.

You can call the **updateMasterDataRange** procedure like this:

```
call updateMasterDataRange (Workbooks(2).Sheets("new").Range("a1"), Workbooks(1).Worksheets("master").Range("a1"))
```

Notice the fully qualified data ranges, including the workbooks and the worksheets in the mix. If you don't prepend these identifiers, VBA will try to associate the unqualified Range with ActiveWorkbook or/and ActiveWorksheet, with unpredictable results.

Here goes the body of the module:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Sub updateMasterDataRange( _
    ByRef dataRangeNew As Range, ByRef dataRangeMaster As Range, _
    Optional refColIndexNew As Integer = 1, Optional refColIndexMaster As Integer = 1, _
    Optional colorAlertOption = True, Optional rangeWithHeaders = True)

    ' Sanitize the supplied data ranges based on various criteria (see procedure's documentation)
    If sanitizeDataRange(dataRangeMaster, rangeWithHeaders) = False Then GoTo rangeError
    If sanitizeDataRange(dataRangeNew, rangeWithHeaders) = False Then GoTo rangeError

    ' Declaring counters for the final report's updated and appended records respectively
    Dim updatedRecords As Integer: updatedRecords = 0
    Dim appendedRecords As Integer: appendedRecords = 0

    ' Declaring the temporary variables which hold intermediate results during the for-loop
    Dim updatableMasterRefCell As Range, currentRowIndex As Integer, updatableRowMaster As Range

    For currentRowIndex = 1 To dataRangeNew.Rows.Count

        ' search the master's unique references (refColMaster range) for the current reference
        ' from dataRangeNew (refcolNew range)
        Set updatableMasterRefCell = dataRangeMaster.Columns(refColIndexMaster).Find( _
            what:=dataRangeNew.Cells(currentRowIndex, refColIndexNew).Value, _
            lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchDirection:=xlNext)

        ' perform a check to see if the search has returned a valid range reference in updatableMasterRefCell
        ' if it is found empty (the reference value in refCellNew is unique to masterDataRange)
        If updatableMasterRefCell Is Nothing Then
            Call appendRecord(dataRangeNew.Rows(currentRowIndex), dataRangeMaster, colorAlertOption)
            appendedRecords = appendedRecords + 1
            'ReDim Preserve appendableRowIndices(appendedRecords)
            'appendableRowIndices(appendedRecords) = currentRowIndex
        Else
            Set updatableRowMaster = Intersect(dataRangeMaster, updatableMasterRefCell.EntireRow)
            Call updateRecord(dataRangeNew.Rows(currentRowIndex), updatableRowMaster, colorAlertOption)
            updatedRecords = updatedRecords + 1
        End If

    Next currentRowIndex

    ' output an informative dialog to the user
    Dim msg As String
    msg = _
        "sheet name: " & dataRangeMaster.Parent.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "records updated: " & updatedRecords & vbCrLf & _
        "records appended: " & appendedRecords
    MsgBox msg, vbOKOnly, "--+ Update report +--"
    Exit Sub

rangeError:
    MsgBox "Either range argument is too small to operate on!", vbExclamation, "Argument Error"
End Sub


Sub appendRecord(ByVal recordRowSource As Range, ByRef dataRangeTarget As Range, Optional ByVal colorAlertOption As Boolean = True)

    Dim appendedRowTarget As Range
    Set dataRangeTarget = dataRangeTarget.Resize(Rowsize:=dataRangeTarget.Rows.Count + 1)
    Set appendedRowTarget = dataRangeTarget.Rows(dataRangeTarget.Rows.Count)
    appendedRowTarget.Insert shift:=xlDown, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Set appendedRowTarget = appendedRowTarget.Offset(-1, 0)
    ' resize datarangetarget to -1 row (because cells' shifting incurred a +1 row to dataRangeTarget)
    Set dataRangeTarget = dataRangeTarget.Resize(Rowsize:=dataRangeTarget.Rows.Count - 1)
    recordRowSource.Copy appendedRowTarget

    If colorAlertOption = True Then
        ' fills the cells of the newly appended row with lightgreen color
        appendedRowTarget.Interior.color = RGB(156, 244, 164)
    End If

End Sub


Sub updateRecord(ByVal recordRowSource As Range, ByVal updatableRowTarget As Range, Optional ByVal colorAlertOption As Boolean = True)
    recordRowSource.Copy updatableRowTarget
    If colorAlertOption = True Then
        ' fills the cells of the updated row with lightblue color
        updatableRowTarget.Interior.color = RGB(164, 189, 249)
    End If
End Sub


Private Function sanitizeDataRange(ByRef target As Range, ByVal rangeWithHeaders As Boolean) As Boolean

    ' if data range comprises only 1 cell then try to expand the range to currentRegion
    ' (all neighbouring cells until the selection reaches boundaries of blank rows or columns)
    If target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Set target = target.CurrentRegion
    End If

    ' remove headers from data ranges if flag RangeWithHeaders is true
    If (rangeWithHeaders) Then
        If (target.Rows.Count >= 2) Then
            Set target = target.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rowsize:=(target.Rows.Count - 1))
        Else
            sanitizeDataRange = False
        End If
    End If

    sanitizeDataRange = IIf((target.Rows.Count >= 1), True, False)

End Function
```

The results of a simple execution on your example gave the expected results, as you can see in the attached picture. There is even a dialogue with a brief report on the accomplished operations.

[image]

Comment: +1 Some people will do anything for points.  :)  (SO says: Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks")

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got much of a start. Will this outline get you started?

```
open all 3 workbooks
for masterrow = beginrow to endrow
  if match in newsheet then
    updaterow = newrow
  else
    updaterow = masterrow
  end if
next masterrow
' now pick up unmatched newrows
for newrow = beginrow to endrow
  if not match in updatesheet then
    updaterow = newrow
  end if
next newrow
```

EDIT: CodeVortex did the whole thing. My outline was flawed.

```
open both workbooks
appendrow = endrow of mastersheet
for newrow = beginrow to endrow
  if match in mastersheet then
    update masterrow
  else
    append into appendrow
    appendrow = appendrow + 1
  end if
next newrow
```